# AWS cognito- create new user giving "Unable to parse the number" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Error :

> Attributes did not conform to the schema: updated_at: Unable to parse
>   the number (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code:
>   400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID:
>   5ffba344-fd14-11e8-ab30-c7065ac22e08)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you refresh the users list in the user pool and check if it created or not? AWS Cognito is sometimes inconsistent in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hit same problem and solved by using CLI.

This error will be occured in case of missing of required attribute.

And you can not set the attributes (family name, middle name....) from web console.
You should use CLI or code to set them like following.

```
aws cognito-idp admin-create-user --user-pool-id dummy --username test1 --user-attributes Name=email,Value=test1@example.com,Name=family_name,Value=Test1,Name=given_name,Value=Taro,Name=updated_at,Value= --profile=dummy --region=ap-northeast-1
```